How To Block VB.NET To AutoFill İnputs And Submit Forms
They use this code to be faster than others and win in the web based game. How can we prevent it? Google captcha or any other type of captcha cannot be used because users need to be fast on this page
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Public Class Form1 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click WebView21.Source = New Uri("URL") End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    WebView21.Source = New Uri("URL")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


    Dim script As String = "document.getElementById('gir').click();"
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)

    Timer1.Interval = 2000
    ' Timer1'i başlatıyoruz. 1.5 saniye sonra Timer1_Tick olayı tetiklenecek.
    Timer1.Start()
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WebView21.Source = New Uri("URL")

    ' Timer'ı durduruyoruz.
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub WebView21_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebView21.NavigationCompleted
    If e.IsSuccess Then
        ' WebView2 sayfası başarılı bir şekilde yüklendi.
        ' TextBox2 ve TextBox3'teki metni alıyoruz
        Dim inputText1 As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim inputText2 As String = TextBox3.Text

        ' JavaScript kodu
        Dim script As String = String.Format("
        // TextBox2'deki metni 'Harcanacak Mermi' alanına aktar
        let textarea1 = document.querySelector('textarea[placeholder=""Harcanacak Mermi""]');
        if (textarea1) {{
            textarea1.value = '{0}';
        }}

        // TextBox3'teki metni 'Kullanıcı Adı' alanına aktar
        let textarea2 = document.querySelector('textarea[placeholder=""Kullanıcı Adı""]');
        if (textarea2) {{
            textarea2.value = '{1}';
        }}
    ", inputText1, inputText2) ' TextBox2 ve TextBox3'teki metni buraya ekliyoruz.

        ' JavaScript kodunu WebView2'ye gönderin ve çalıştırın
        WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim securityCodeText As String = TextBox1.Text

    ' JavaScript kodu: WebView2 içinde 'id="APjFqb"' olan textarea'ya metni yazıyoruz
    ' Metnin tamamını aktarmak için textarea'nın maxlength özelliğini kaldırıyoruz.
    ' Ayrıca metnin başındaki ve sonundaki boşlukları temizliyoruz.
    Dim script As String = "
    // 'APjFqb' id'li textarea'yı buluyoruz
    let textarea = document.getElementById('APjFqb');
    if (textarea) {
        // maxlength özelliğini kaldırıyoruz
        textarea.removeAttribute('maxlength');
        
        // TextBox1'deki metni almak ve baştaki/sondaki boşlukları kaldırmak
        let cleanedText = '" & securityCodeText.Replace("'", "\'").Trim() & "';
        
        // Temizlenmiş metni textarea'ya aktarıyoruz
        textarea.value = cleanedText;
    }
"

    ' JavaScript kodunu WebView2 içinde çalıştırıyoruz
    WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim script As String = "document.getElementById('button').click();"

    ' JavaScript kodunu WebView2 içinde çalıştırıyoruz
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
    Timer2.Interval = 2002
    Timer2.Start()
    TextBox4.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Timer2.Stop()

    ' WebView2 içinde JavaScript ile sayfayı yönlendiriyoruz
    Dim redirectScript As String = "window.location.href = 'URL';"
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(redirectScript)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
    Dim securityCodeText As String = TextBox4.Text

    ' WebView2 içinde JavaScript kodu çalıştırarak metni "guvenlik_kodu" id'li input kutusuna yazıyoruz
    Dim script As String = "document.getElementsByName('captcha_code')[0].value = '" & securityCodeText.Replace("'", "\'") & "';"

    ' JavaScript kodunu WebView2 içinde çalıştırıyoruz
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim script As String = "document.getElementsByName('Submit')[0].click();"

    ' JavaScript kodunu WebView2 içinde çalıştırıyoruz
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim script As String = "document.getElementById('butonid').click();"
    Timer2.Interval = 2000
    Timer2.Start()
    ' JavaScript kodunu WebView2 içinde çalıştırıyoruz
    WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(script)
    TextBox4.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

End Sub

End Class

tried to block edge but they can change it, added a fake input but they can look and change the code. i blocked inspect on the site, inputs has a unique names and ids every time

CSRF protection is probably what you need here. i.e. a unique token generated every time the form is generated in a new copy of your page. The value is different every time the form is shown. The user needs to submit that unique value back every time they submit the form, and the server to check it before processing the form. This makes it very difficult for a bot script (aside from, perhaps, a headless browser), unless it can read that new value each time. Also, using JavaScript on the page to do something which is vital to the functionality adds another layer of complexity for bots.

This question was previously closed. Please don't delete and re-post the exact same question - it seems that you also break the rules. Lead by example. If you want people around you to act with integrity, then you need to act with integrity first.

Such code is not faster, and does NOT prevent a post-back, and does not prevent the page lifecycle from occurring. Any code behind that injects script is STILL 100% based on a full page round trip, and thus you gain ZERO in terms of performance here.  I strong, but REALLY strong suggest you move away from your thinking that such script injection on a button click will save, help, or gain you ANY performance here - it will not!. If you want to prevent a post-back, then adopt a jQuery.ajax call, and place web methods in your code. Or go the super easy road, and adopt a update panel.

@AlbertD.Kallal I think by "faster" they mean "faster than a human clicking on the page in a browser". This is a client-side automation script designed to auto fill bits of a web page instantly - a simple bot, in other words. It's not an attempt to make the site itself more efficient (from the original tags used on this post, it seems the target site may be written in php)

@ADyson Yes, they use this bot to be faster than humans. The page is coded in php. You can think of it as 2 people fighting on the page. The fastest one wins. The people who build this bot quickly attack and protect themselves.

Well, the server side code could set a session() value, or perhaps even check the referring URL to prevent this. Not having the actual web page and source code, it's hard to tell, since we don't have that code. I for example have a feedback button in my topmost menu bar. However, while it is part of the "master page", I only show and allow the code to run if the user is a valid logged in user. So, on a daily basis, for some reason some bots "attempt" to submit feedback, but such bots fail since they are not logged into the site before attempting to fill the feedback page via code.

My code also checks the referring URL, and if that's not a valid page from the current site, then again my code rejects this "auto filled out" submit by such bots. It's not at all clear why you asking a question, showing some VB code, but then admit the page is PHP, probably not even asp.net, and certainly not VB, and thus none of that page is under your control anyway. And if it WAS under your control, then you would have posted the server side PHP and server markup of that page. ZERO sense to post some vb code for some page that is not even vb and not even asp.net code. This is PHP question.

It's true, we would have a far better idea of how to defend the site if we could see the relevant bits of the PHP code

they launching bot and logging manually than going the vs page. the bot fills inputs auto but cant fill security question. visitors fill it manually and they click attack button and kills real player, after click bot redirects to shelter page and enters to shelter. (he is going shelter because other player cant fight him on there) we cant add captcha on attack page because they need to be fast as they can.
we blocked edge but they changed user agent
we added captcha to shelter but its not important
we added fake inputs so bot fills the fakes but they can changes bot codes

example video https://streamable.com/4swhp1
@ADyson

The attack command sends something to the server, I guess? If so then like I said maybe you can use one-time tokens. Depends how sophisticated these bot-writers are. And, again, without seeing any relevant game code it's nearly impossible to suggest anything more. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.

If one makes something publicly available, one can't prevent others from misusing it. While one may be able to make it more difficult or temporarily prevent something, someone with nefarious intentions who is motivated will eventually find a way around whatever one has put in place to hinder him/her/them.
